# maximum subarray whose sum equals 0

Tags: algorithm

An array contains both positive and negative elements, find the maximum subarray whose sum equals 0.

Comment: Empty subarray has zero sum. :)

Comment: Isn't the usual question to find the largest subarray?

Answer (score 76):

**The link in the current accepted answer requires to sign up for a membership and I do not its content.**

This algorithm will find all subarrays with sum 0 and it can be easily modified to find the minimal one or to keep track of the start and end indexes. This algorithm is **O(n)**.

Given an `int[] input` array, you can create an `int[] tmp` array where `tmp[i] = tmp[i - 1] + input[i];` Each element of tmp will store the sum of the input up to that element(prefix sum of array).

Now if you check tmp, you'll notice that there might be values that are equal to each other. Let's say that this values are at indexes `j an k with j < k`, then the sum of the input till `j` is equal to the sum till `k` and this means that the sum of the portion of the array between `j` and `k` is 0! Specifically the 0 sum subarray will be from index j + 1 to k.

- NOTE: if `j + 1 == k`, then `k is 0` and that's it! ;)
- NOTE: The algorithm should consider a virtual `tmp[-1] = 0`;
- NOTE: An empty array has sum 0 and it's minimal and this special case should be brought up as well in an interview. Then the interviewer will say that doesn't count but that's another problem! ;)

The implementation can be done in different ways including using a HashMap with  pairs but be careful with the special case in the NOTE section above.

Example:

```
int[] input = {4,  6,  3, -9, -5, 1, 3, 0, 2}
int[] tmp =   {4, 10, 13,  4, -1, 0, 3, 3, 5}
```

- Value 4 in tmp at index 0 and 3 ==> sum tmp 1 to 3 = 0, length (3 - 1) + 1 = 3
- Value 0 in tmp at index 5 ==> sum tmp 0 to 5 = 0, length (5 - 0) + 1 = 6
- Value 3 in tmp at index 6 and 7 ==> sum tmp 7 to 7 = 0, length (7 - 7) + 1 = 1

****UPDATE****

Assuming that in our tmp array we end up with multiple element with the same value then you have to consider every identical pair in it! Example (keep in mind the virtual '0' at index '-1'):

```
int[] array = {0, 1, -1, 0}
int[] tmp = {0, 1, 0, 0}
```

By applying the same algorithm described above the 0-sum subarrays are delimited by the following indexes (included):

`[0] [0-2] [0-3] [1-2] [1-3] [3]`

Although the presence of multiple entries with the same value might impact the complexity of the algorithm depending on the implementation, I believe that by using an inverted index on tmp (mapping a value to the indexes where it appears) we can keep the running time at O(n).

Comment: >> Consider this test-case: 0, 1, -1, 0 the temp array is 0, 1, 0, 0 So, according to you, how many sub-arrays are there whose sum is zero?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this special case out, please see my update to the answer above. There should be 6 (+ the empty array if you want)!

Comment: why isn't this answer accepted? i can see it works just fine.

Comment: can you elaborate how to keep O(n) running time when there are a considerable amount of duplicate entries? thanks

Comment: @shreyasva you should accept this answer. Are you seeing any issues with it?

Comment: @Gevorg Can this algorithm be tweeked for finding summation to k instead of 0?

Comment: Even if each int in `array` is of bounded size, I think that the size in bits of the values in `tmp` would be `O(log n)`, right?  Imagine the case where everything in `array` was 1.  Then the biggest value in `tmp` would be `n`, and so the length of elements in `tmp` would be `O(log n)`.  So that would present a problem for using an inverted index.  A hash map would still be possible, but hashing something of size `k` in bits takes at least `O(k)` time.  So I think that even if the size of ints in `array` is bounded, this would still be `O(n log n)` at best.

Comment: this will work only if numbers making the same are consecutive . Consider the case (5,-3,2,-2), it will not work

Answer (score 7):

This is one the same lines as suggested by Gevorg but I have used a hash map for quick lookup. O(n) complexity used extra space though.

```
private static void subArraySumsZero()
{
    int [] seed = new int[] {1,2,3,4,-9,6,7,-8,1,9};
    int currSum = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> sumMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < seed.length ; i ++)
    {
        currSum += seed[i];
        if(currSum == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("subset : { 0 - " + i + " }");
        }
        else if(sumMap.get(currSum) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("subset : { " 
                                + (sumMap.get(currSum) + 1) 
                                + " - " + i + " }");
            sumMap.put(currSum, i);
        }
        else
            sumMap.put(currSum, i);
    }
    System.out.println("HASH MAP HAS: " + sumMap);
}
```

The output generated has index of elements (zero based):

```
subset : { 1 - 4 }
subset : { 3 - 7 }
subset : { 6 - 8 }
```

Comment: Your implementation has a problem. 

 For the array [4,10,-6,-4,0,2,3,-5,1,0,2] 

Your output will be - {1 3} {4}{5 7} {9} 

Actual answer should be {1 3}{4}{5 7}{9}{1 4}{1 5} {1 7} {4 7}

Comment: @DJ': {1, 5} shouldn't be in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
1. Given A[i]
  A[i] | 2 |  1 | -1 | 0 | 2 | -1 | -1
-------+---|----|--------|---|----|---
sum[i] | 2 |  3 |  2 | 2 | 4 |  3 |  2

2. sum[i] = A[0] + A[1] + ...+ A[i]
3. build a map<Integer, Set>
4. loop through array sum, and lookup map to get the set and generate set, and push <sum[i], i> into map.

Complexity O(n)
```

Comment: this will work only if numbers making the same are consecutive

Answer (score 2):

Here's my implementation, it's the obvious approach so it's probably sub-optimized, but at least its clear. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Starts from each index of the array and calculates and compares the individual sums (tempsum) with the desired sum (in this case, sum = 0). Since the integers are signed, we must calculate every possible combination.

If you don't need the full list of sub-arrays, you can always put conditions in the inner loop to break out of it. (Say you just want to know if such a sub-array exists, just return true when tempsum = sum).

```
public static string[] SubArraySumList(int[] array, int sum)
{
    int tempsum;
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        tempsum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < array.Length; j++)
        {
            tempsum += array[j];
            if (tempsum == sum)
            {
                list.Add(String.Format("[{0}-{1}]", i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Calling the function:

```
int[] array = SubArraySumList(new int { 0, -1, 1, 0 }, 0));
```

Printing the contents of the output array:

```
[0-0], [0-2], [0-3], [1-2], [1-3], [3-3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following solution finds max length subarray with a given sum k without using dynamic programming, but using simple rescursion. Here i_s is start index and i_e is end index for the current value of sum

```
##Input the array and sum to be found(0 in your case)
a = map(int,raw_input().split())
k = int(raw_input())

##initialize total sum=0
totalsum=0

##Recursive function to find max len 0
def findMaxLen(sumL,i_s,i_e):
    if i_s<len(a)-1 and i_e>0: 
        if sumL==k:
            print i_s, i_e
            return (i_s,i_e)
        else:
            x = findMaxLen(sumL-a[i_s],i_s+1,i_e)
            y = findMaxLen(sumL-a[i_e],i_s,i_e-1)
            if x[1]-x[0]>y[1]-y[0]:
                return x
            else:
                return y
    else:
        ##Result not there
        return (-1,-1)


## find total sum
for i in range(len(a)):
    totalsum += a[i]

##if totalsum==0, max array is array itself
if totalsum == k:
    print "seq found at",0,len(a)-1

##else use recursion
else:
    print findMaxLen(totalsum,0,len(a)-1)
```

Time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(n) due to recursive memory stack

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `O(n)` implementation in [java](/questions/tagged/java)

The idea is to iterate through the given array and for every element `arr[i]`, calculate sum of elements form `0` to `i`, store each `sum` in `HashMap`.

- If an element is `0`, it's considerd as a a *ZeroSum* sub array.
- if `sum` became `0`, then there is a *ZeroSum* sub array, from `0` to `i`.
- If the current sum has been seen before in `HashMap`, then there is a *ZeroSum* sub array, from that point to `i`.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    private static final int[] EMPTY = {};
    // Returns int[] if arr[] has a subarray with sero sum
    static int[] findZeroSumSubarray(int arr[])
    {
        if (arr.length == 0) return EMPTY;
        // Creates an empty hashMap hM
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hM = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        // Initialize sum of elements
        int sum = 0;        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {   
            sum += arr[i]; 
            if (arr[i] == 0)   //Current element is 0
            {
               return new int[]{0}; 
            }
            else if (sum == 0)  // sum of elements from 0 to i is 0
            {
                return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, i+1);
            }
            else if (hM.get(sum) != null) // sum is already present in hash map
            {
                return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, hM.get(sum)+1, i+1);
            }
            else
            {
                // Add sum to hash map
                hM.put(sum, i);
            }
        }    
        // We reach here only when there is no subarray with 0 sum
        return null;
    }        

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        //int arr[] = {};
        int arr[] = { 2, -3, 1, 4, 6}; //Case left
        //int arr[] = { 0, 2, -3, 1, 4, 6}; //Case 0
        //int arr[] = { 4, 2, -3, 1, 4}; // Case middle
        int result[] = findZeroSumSubarray(arr);
        if (result == EMPTY){
            System.out.println("An empty array is ZeroSum, LOL"); 
        }
        else if ( result != null){
            System.out.println("Found a subarray with 0 sum :" );
            for (int i: result) System.out.println(i);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("No Subarray with 0 sum");            
    }           
}
```

Please see the experiment here: http://rextester.com/PAKT41271

Answer (score 0):

An array contains positive and negative numbers. Find the sub-array that has the maximum sum

```
public static int findMaxSubArray(int[] array)
{
    int max=0,cumulativeSum=0,i=0,start=0,end=0,savepoint=0;
    while(i<array.length)
    {
        if(cumulativeSum+array[i]<0)
        {
            cumulativeSum=0;
            savepoint=start;
            start=i+1;
        }
        else
            cumulativeSum=cumulativeSum+array[i];
        if(cumulativeSum>max)
        {
                max=cumulativeSum;
                savepoint=start;
                end=i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println("Max : "+max+"  Start indices : "+savepoint+"  end indices : "+end);
    return max;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below codes can find out every possible sub-array that has a sum being a given number, and (of course) it can find out the shortest and longest sub-array of that kind.

```
public static void findGivenSumSubarray(int arr[], int givenSum) {
    int sum = 0;
    int sStart = 0, sEnd = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1;  // Start & end position of the shortest sub-array
    int lStart = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1, lEnd = 0;  // Start & end position of the longest  sub-array

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> sums = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();

    indices.add(-1);
    sums.put(0, indices);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        indices = sums.get(sum - givenSum);
        if(indices != null) {
            for(int index : indices) {
                System.out.println("From #" + (index + 1) + " to #" + i);
            }
            if(i - indices.get(indices.size() - 1) < (sEnd - sStart + 1)) {
                sStart = indices.get(indices.size() - 1) + 1;
                sEnd = i;
            }
            if(i - indices.get(0) > (lEnd - lStart + 1)) {
                lStart = indices.get(0) + 1;
                lEnd = i;
            }
        }
        indices = sums.get(sum);
        if(indices == null) {
            indices = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        indices.add(i);
        sums.put(sum, indices);
    }

    System.out.println("Shortest sub-arry: Length = " + (sEnd - sStart + 1) + ", [" + sStart + " - " + sEnd + "]");
    System.out.println("Longest  sub-arry: Length = " + (lEnd - lStart + 1) + ", [" + lStart + " - " + lEnd + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
 private static void subArrayZeroSum(int array[] , int findSum){
    Map<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>();
    int sum = 0;
   for(int index = 0 ; index < array.length ; index ++){
       sum +=array[index];
       if(array[index] == findSum){
           System.out.println(" ["+index+"]");
       }
       if(sum == findSum && index > 0){
           System.out.println(" [ 0 , "+index+" ]");
       }
       if(map.containsKey(sum)){
           HashSet<Integer> set = map.get(sum);
           if(set == null)
               set = new HashSet<Integer>();

           set.add(index);
           map.put(sum, set);

           for(int val : set){

               if(val + 1 != index && (val + 1) < index){
                  System.out.println("["+(val + 1) +","+index+" ]");
               }
           }

        }else{
            HashSet<Integer> set = map.get(sum);
               if(set == null)
                   set = new HashSet<Integer>();
               set.add(index);
            map.put(sum, set);
        }
   }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution:

Let's say we have an array of integer,
int[] arr = {2,1,-1,-2};

We will traverse using the for loop until we find the number < 0 OR <= 0
i = 2;

With the inner loop, we will traverse assign the value to j = i-1
So, We can able to find the positive value.

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      int j = 0;
      int sum = arr[i];
      if(arr[i] < 0){
      j = i - 1;
}
```

We will have one sum variable, which maintaining the sum of arr[i] and arr[j] and updating the result.

If the sum is < 0 then, we have to move left side of the array and so, we will decrement the j by one, j--

```
for(j = i-1; j>=0; j--) {
      sum = sum + arr[j];
      if(sum == 0){
      System.out.println("Index from j=" + j+ " to i=" + i);
      return true;
   }
}
```

If the sum is > 0 then, we have to move right side of the array and so, we will increment the i

When we find the sum == 0 then we can print the j and i index and return or break the loop.

And so, It's complete in a linear time. As well we don't need to use any other data structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem could be:
1. Calculate sum for entire array
2. Now follow following formula to get the largest subarray with sum zero:

```
Math.max(find(a,l+1,r,sum-a[l]), find(a,l,r-1,sum-a[r]));
where l=left index, r= right index, initially their value=0 and a.length-1
```

Idea is simple, max size we can get with sum=0, is the size of array then we start skipping elements from left and right recursively, the moment we get sum=0 we stop. Below is the code for same:

```
static int find(int a[]) {
    int sum =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        sum = sum+a[i];
    }

    return find(a, 0, a.length-1, sum);
}


static int find(int a[], int l, int r, int sum) {
    if(l==r && sum>0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(sum==0) {
        return r-l+1;
    }
    return Math.max(find(a,l+1,r,sum-a[l]), find(a,l,r-1,sum-a[r]));

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help.

```
int v[DIM] = {2, -3,  1,  2,  3,  1,  4, -6,  7, -5, -1};
int i,j,sum=0,counter=0;

    for (i=0; i<DIM; i++) {
        sum = v[i];
        counter=0;
        for (j=i+1; j<DIM;j++) {
            sum += v[j];
            counter++;
            if (sum == 0) {
                printf("Sub-array starting from index %d, length %d.\n",(j-counter),counter +1);
            }
        }
    }
```