# Zero sum minimal subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zero sum SubArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534063/zero-sum-subarray)

> An array contains both positive and negative elements, find the
>   subarray whose sum equals 0.

This is an interview question. 
Unfortunately, I cannot read the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534063/zero-sum-subarray), so I am asking it again: how to find the minimal integer subarray with zero sum?

Note, this is not a "zero subset problem". The obvious brute-force solution is O(N^2) (loop over all subarrays). Can we solve it in O(N)?

Comment: Do not post the question if you see it as a dupe. If you think answers there are insufficeient: you should comment on them and/or put bounty on this [original] question to get the increased attention.

Comment: @amit The original "Zero sum SubArray" question is broken as stated by Michael in this question! The accepted answer has a link that is not available anymore

Answer (score 5):

This algorithm will find them all, you can easily modify it to find the minimal subarray.

Given an `int[] input array`, you can create an `int[] tmp` array where `tmp[i] = tmp[i - 1] + input[i];` so that at each element of tmp will store the sum of the input up to that element.

Now if you check tmp, you'll notice that there might be values that are equal to each other. Let's say that this values are at indexes `j` an `k` with `j < k`, then the subarray with sum 0 will be from index `j + 1` to `k`. NOTE: if `j + 1 == k`, then `k is 0` and that's it! ;)

**NOTE**: The algorithm should consider a virtual `tmp[-1] = 0;`

The implementation can be done in different ways including using a HashMap as suggested by BrokenGlass but be careful with the special case in the NOTE above.

Example:

```
int[] input = {4,  6,  3, -9, -5, 1, 3, 0, 2}
int[] tmp =   {4, 10, 13,  4, -1, 0, 3, 3, 5}
```

- Note the value 4 in tmp at index 0 and 3 ==> sum tmp 1 to 3 = 0, length (3 - 1) + 1 = 4
- Note the value 0 in tmp at index 5 ==> sum tmp 0 to 5 = 0, length (5 - 0) + 1 = 6
- Note the value 3 in tmp at index 6 and 7 ==> sum tmp 7 to 7 = 0, length (7 - 7) + 1 = 1

Answer (score 4):

> An array contains both positive and negative elements, find the
>   subarray whose sum equals 0.

Yes that can be done in O(n). If the sum of the elements within a subarray equals zero that means the sum of elements up to the first element before the sub array is the same as the sum of elements up to the last element in the subarray.

Go through the array and for each element K put the sum up to K and the index K in a hashtable, if the sum up to the current element exists already check the index of that element and the current element, if the delta is lower than the minimum subarray length, update the minimum. Update the hashtable with (sum, current index K).

Comment: That isn't really O(n) when you're searching in a hash table on each element though.

Comment: O(1) lookup in hashtable/map for last index with same sum, sum is key in the map

Comment: Only if there was a limited number of possible sums.

Comment: @Detheroc: While you are correct using hash table ops is not `O(1)` worst case, it is on average case. For almost any case this solution will provide `O(n)` run time, but it indeed might detoriarate to `O(n^2)` worst case on some bizare edge cases. If you are worried about these worst cases, you could use a balanced tree or other sorted container, and get `O(nlogn)` worst+average time complexity.