# Searching for all intervals meeting a specific condition

Tags: algorithm, intervals, pascal, lazarus

How can I search for all intervals in an array of `0`s, `1`s and `2`s that contain the same amount of `1`s and `2`s?

Example:

```
[0,1,1,2,2]
```

Would return 3 intervals

```
[0,1,1,2,2] [1,1,2,2] [1,2]
```

I don't want to brute force it. Is there any very simple algorithm which can be used for such instances? I'd need something flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put -1 instead of 2 in the original array. Then, the problem will be reduced to this: [Zero sum SubArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534063/zero-sum-subarray)

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up using myself during the competition! But thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, for clarity in the algorithm, I'm going to change the numbers to letters: Z, A, B.  The input can now be represented as a simple string: "ZAABB".  Also for clarity, I'm going to insert a period at each position, for spacing: ".Z.A.A.B.B.".

This is a symbol balancing problem, easy enough to handle.  Iterate through the array, keeping track of the excess at each position.  `Z` doesn't change the count; `A` increments; `B` decrements.  This gives us

```
"00011221100".
```

Now, extract alternate counts, the count at each "spacer", the periods:

```
".Z.A.A.B.B."
"0 0 1 2 1 0"
```

From here, its simple to find matching counts.  *Every* pair of matching counts gives you the indices of a substring with the same quantity of `A` and `B`.  You have three pairs of 0 matches and one pair of 1 matches, yielding the substrings

"**0 0** 1 2 1 0"     Z

"**0** 0 1 2 1 **0**"     Z A A B B

"0 **0** 1 2 1 **0**"     A A B B

"0 0 **1** 2 **1** 0"     A B

Is that clear enough for you to implement?